# Using DiffUtil, How to prevent blocking the main thread when updating the recyclerView contained in a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to udate my recyclerView in background Thread without any succes.

Updating the recyclerView still block the main thread.

Here my adapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    
        private List<PostItems> postList;
        private Context context;
        private Queue<List<PostItems>> pendingUpdates = new ArrayDeque<>();
    
        PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postList, Context context) {
            this.postList = postList;
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_wall_post, parent, false);
            return new PostViewHolder(v);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
            PostItems post_items = postList.get(position);
                 ...
                 ...
                 .........
                 ...
                 ...
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return postList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ...
                ...
                .........
                ...
                ...
            }
        }
    }


/*
* here the background Thread
* 
*/

// The Fragment or Activity will call this method
    // when new data becomes available
    public void updateItems(final List<PostItems> newItems) {
        pendingUpdates.add(newItems);
        if (pendingUpdates.size() > 1) {
            return;
        }
        updateItemsInternal(newItems);
    }
    // This method does the heavy lifting of
    // pushing the work to the background thread
    void updateItemsInternal(final List<PostItems> newItems) {
        final List<PostItems> oldItems = new ArrayList<>(this.postList);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult =
                        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffCb(oldItems, newItems));
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        applyDiffResult(newItems, diffResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
    // This method is called when the background work is done
    protected void applyDiffResult(List<PostItems> newItems,
                                   DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        pendingUpdates.remove();
        dispatchUpdates(newItems, diffResult);
        if (pendingUpdates.size() > 0) {
            updateItemsInternal(pendingUpdates.peek());
        }
    }
    // This method does the work of actually updating
    // the backing data and notifying the adapter
    protected void dispatchUpdates(List<PostItems> newItems,
                                   DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
        postList.clear();
        postList.addAll(newItems);
        Toast.makeText(context, "b"+postList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Here is my DiffUtil class:

```
class DiffCb extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private final List<PostItems> oldItems;
    private final List<PostItems> newItems;

    public DiffCb(List<PostItems> oldItems, List<PostItems> newItems) {
        this.oldItems = oldItems;
        this.newItems = newItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newItems.size();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldItems.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newItems.get(newItemPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldItems.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newItems.get(newItemPosition));
    }
}
```

Updating recyclerView like that:

```
postList.addAll(response.body());
postAdapter.updateItems(homePostList);
```

Everything work fine when my recyclerView is not contained in a NestedScrollView or ScrollView.

But when my recyclerView is contained in a NestedScrollView or ScrollView, updating the recyclerView keep blocking the `main thread` as if the DiffUtil were disabled.

How to prevent blocking the `main thread` when updating the recyclerView contained in a NestedScrollView or ScrollView ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not create everytime new adapter, but instead update data inside adapter. Also if you use `DiffUtils`, you should override `.equals` and `.hashcode` in your `PostItems` class so `DIffUtils` can know which object is new and which object already exists.

Click right mouse in somewhere your `PostItems` class  and choose `Generate`, then choose `override equals and hashcode`, then choose unique field in class.

Also you should bind views in your ViewHolder class
For example:

```
       static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView tv1;
            TextView tv2;
            PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tv1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                tv2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            }
        }
```

Then in `.bindViewHolder` method you access your view like:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostItems post_items = postList.get(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(post_items.get_text_wall_post());
        //etc
    }
```

Main idea is to not call everytime `.findViewById()` in `.bindViewHolder` method, because it's slow enaugh for `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks but your answer has nothing helpful with my question.