# Is it possible to make layout scrollable without using the scroll views(ScrollView, NestedScrollVIew...)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

Hellow,
Bellow is my layout:

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/color_dark_red">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="640dp"
                android:background="@color/color_black"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_1" />
            
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:background="#0f0">

            </RelativeLayout>
            
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Below the screenshot:

[image]

I want to hide the `layout_1` when user scroll down the recyclerView or hide the `layout_2` when user scroll up the recyclerView.

According to the docs:
**Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience.**

I also don't want to use the `NestedScrollView` because it disable(or remove) the DiffUtil work when the recyclerView is being updated in `background Thread` as asked in the following question:

[Using DiffUtil, How to prevent blocking the main thread when updating the recyclerView contained in a NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196657/using-diffutil-how-to-prevent-blocking-the-main-thread-when-updating-the-recycl)

How could I make the scroll down of `recycler_view` hide the `layout_1` and scroll up hide the `layout_2`
without using ScrollView or NestedScrollView ?

Thanks.

Comment: In your case i think is possible to simulate the collapsing view effect in your layout_1 and layout_2.  You could to use the RecyclerView listeners to handle when the user is scrolling the list and then apply an animation in the views to hide or show them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use recyclerView scroll listner

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
        // show the last item 
    }
 }
});
```